Understanding updates on entities with relationships in Spring/JPA
Background
I am trying to understand how Hibernate will handle a series of complex updates on entities tied by relationships. Please let me know if my understandings are correct or not.
class User {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private List<Document> documents;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  private List<ContactInfo> contactInfos;
}

And for DAO, we can have simple repositories + 1 service to facade the operations:
class DocumentService {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;
  private final DocumentRepository documentRepository;

  public User updateUser(User user) {
    if (!userRepository.existsById(user.getId())) {
       throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
    // My understanding: this should propagate changes from User -> ContactInfo
    return userRepository.save(user);
  }

  public User findUserById(String userId) {
     return userRepository.findById(userId).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException());
  }
}

I know that some of the relationships exposed are not ideal, but I'm not trying to fix them. I want to understand how Hibernate will work on the scenarios below. For each scenario, I will pose a question, so if someone could help it would be great for me.
Problem description
The confusion starts when I want to update User and one or more ContactInfo from a single Document. For this purpose, we can assume that everything happens in a single transaction, since every @Transactional block is set by default to @Transactional(propagation = REQUIRED).
First scenario
Trying to update User from Document.

void useCase1(Document document) {
  User user = document.getUser();
  // Make updates to user

  // Update entity
  documentService.updateUser(user);
}

void useCase2(Document document) {
  User user = documentService.findUserById(document.getUser().getId());
  // Make updates to user ...

  // Update entity
  documentService.updateUser(user);
}


Question: is there any difference between useCase1 and useCase2? My experiments showcase that useCase1 can throw PessimisticLockingFailureException, whereas useCase2 can throw OptimisticLockingFailureException. Is my observation correct?
Second scenario
Trying to update ContactInfo from Document.
void useCase3(Document document, String addressLine1) {
  User user = document.getUser();
  List<ContactInfo> contactInfos = user.getContactInfos();
  
  // add addressLine1 to the ELEMENTS in the list. So right in the entities, not to a copy of the object

  // update entities
  documentService.updateUser(user);
}

void useCase4(Document document, String addressLine1) {
  User user = documentService.findUserById(document.getUser().getId());
  List<ContactInfo> contactInfos = user.getContactInfos();
  
  // add addressLine1 to the ELEMENTS in the list. So right in the entities, not to a copy of the object

  // update entities
  documentService.updateUser(user);
}

Question: Is there a difference between useCase3 or useCase4? My experiments suggest that, by using useCase4 I will end up fetching an outdated list of of contactInfos, while useCase3 will get me the one I updated. Is this perhaps related to Hibernate caching?


Is there any difference between useCase1 and useCase2? My experiments showcase that useCase1 can throw PessimisticLockingFailureException, whereas useCase2 can throw OptimisticLockingFailureException. Is my observation correct?

There is a difference in what entities you might be changing and those may have an influence on how saving works.
In usecase 1 you directly change the user you get via document.getUser(). This may be an attached or detached entity or be lazily loaded (your post doesn't state that).
In usecase 2 you're just using the user's id to load the user so you'll get an attached entity to change.
So what's the difference?

When doing a lazy load in usecase 1 this is basically similar to usecase 2.
When the user is already attached Hibernate will track the changes and update them. It may or may not apply optimistic locking (depends on whether there is a @Version somewhere).
When the user is detached Hibernate will try a merge, i.e. it will load the user and merge your changes into it.

As for pessimistic vs optimistic locking: that depends on how you set your model and your database.
Pessimistic locking means your database doesn't allow changes to a record because some other transaction already locks it. Hibernate might to some pessimistic locking of its own but I didn't use that myself so can't provide any more details.
Optimistic locking depends on the presence of some version (timestamp or number). When doing the updates Hibernate will then add a condition WHERE version = :expectedVersion and track whether the query did an update or not. It may also already check those versions before even contacting the database, especially when trying to merge a detached entity.

Is there a difference between useCase3 or useCase4? My experiments suggest that, by using useCase4 I will end up fetching an outdated list of of contactInfos, while useCase3 will get me the one I updated. Is this perhaps related to Hibernate caching?

Here the same difference may apply as for usecases 1 and 2. In usecase 3 the list of contact info may be detached while usecase 4 (re)loads the list from the database.
Your observation of getting an "outdated" list in usecase 4 may be due to the fact that changes you did to the list have not been committed to the database or are not visible yet. That may be due to several reasons:

The entities are detached
You disabled auto-commit and didn't commit yet.
There's another transaction where you did the changes and that one is not committed yet.

